# I can't simulate credit card failures via rejection trigger in the PayPal Sandbox. What is the right flow?

Tags: triggers, paypal-sandbox, manual-testing

Hi guys I am trying to simulate card errors in the sandbox. But can't understand how I can trigger it...
**Simulate card errors**
To simulate credit card failures, pass a rejection trigger in the First Name or Name on Card field in your existing advanced credit and debit card payment integration. You must use a Visa test card number, for example 4012 8888 8888 1881. Use any date in the future for the card expiry date and any three-digit number for the CVV field.
https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/sandbox/card-testing/#link-simulatecarderrors
**Rejection triggers**
https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/sandbox/card-testing/#link-rejectiontriggers

Steps:

1. Go to the dev.pay pay
2. Create some personal ACC in the sandbox
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVnmf.png)
3. 3. Going to the https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ and log in with this acc
4. Make a Visa card as a prefer and change the address to the CCREJECT-BANK_ERROR
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJnGC.jpg)
5. Go to the Sandbox payment and haven't any payment rejection

I also tried to change the name, but the payment either goes through completely or gives an error without even reaching the payment...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lENiA.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiaC1.jpg)

Sorry, I spent a lot of time on this and still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong... Could you tell me?

Answer (score 0):

The list of pre-generated card numbers can only be used for Advanced Credit and Debit Card integrations.

For payments on a PayPal.com checkout page or with the standard "Debit or Credit Card" black button, a newly-generated (random) card from https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/sandbox/card-testing/#link-creditcardgeneratorfortesting must be used.

To simulate a decline, use `CCREJECT-REFUSED` in the name or address line 1.  Depending on what you are testing you may need to add the card to a [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) payer account with a normal address and change the address line 1 to `CCREJECT-REFUSED` *after* adding it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
•I Created a new sandbox acc
•Then added generated VISA СС with an address from the default VISA (1400)
•Then I edit generated VISA and add the new address with **CCREJECT-REFUSED** in the first input field [Screen](https://prnt.sc/Q7O6dBb4kYMg) and [Screen](https://prnt.sc/RlT5_FpEdCsW) and [Screen](https://prnt.sc/-nR6-zTaZhhd)
• I try to buy with this card [Screen](https://prnt.sc/PgvEcqbNUGtE) error: "Sorry, we weren't able to authorize your card.."
• If i use Default VISA(2351) Purchase completed successfully(
[Screen](https://prnt.sc/7Dh-Apu3YYJw)
What am I missing?(

Comment: Change the address after approving an order but before capturing it

Comment: Did I get it right? I choose a unit of goods for payment on test.env. • sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow is opened in the pop-up [Screen](https://prnt.sc/3iyoy7D0tYDP) There are cards with normal addresses  • I click on the "Agree & Continue" [Screen](https://prnt.sc/4rTqUVWD5wvD)• Then I change my "Address 1" to any trigger from list... Example: **CCREJECT-REFUSED** [Screen](https://prnt.sc/pa_VuDH9FDdv) and trying to buy. I receive in this case a successful payment. Should I see a rejection error in this case, or should I change the address sooner? at the stage of choosing a card for payment?